# Angular 2 formControlName

Tags: angular

### Update

Scroll down to see the original question.

Based on David Walschots' answer below, I realized that I missed the switch from `[formControl]` to `formControlName`.

formControl was expecting a FormControl property which was in the component (as seen here):

[image]

were as `formControlName` is expecting a string,  which following the guide, setting it as `formControlName="name"`,  rather than `[formControlName]="'name'"`,  would be the preferred way of setting it.

[image]

### Original Question

I am going through the [Angular 2 Reactive Forms Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html)

One thing I don't understand is that originally they show the `formControlName` inside [] 
[image: brackets]

and then later they omit the [],
[image: no_bracktes] which seems wrong, but including the [] in the examples fails.

Looking at the source code I see that `formControlName` is an alias for `name`,

[image: formcontrolclass]

so I tried using `[name]="name"` and that works.  So it seems like an
aliased input property can not use the aliased name inside []. **Is that the way it is supposed to work?**

Looking at the document for @Input() inside the [Directives documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) it seems like the alias name should work inside [].

[image]
**Can anyone explain what's going on here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is not using `formControlName` but `formControl`, which is a different directive. As described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlDirective-directive.html):

> FormControlDirective is designed to be used as a standalone control. Unlike FormControlName, it does not require that your FormControl instance be part of any parent FormGroup.

The example uses `[formControl]`, because the given "name" is actually a reference to a `FormControl` which is part of the component's properties:

```js
export class HeroDetailComponent1 {
  name = new FormControl();
}
```

When you want Angular to interpret what is in between the quotation marks, you use `[]`. Otherwise the value between quotation marks is interpreted as a string.

The `formControlName` attribute expects a string, which is why no further interpretation is needed and `[]` has been omitted.

**Another example**

```
[attribute1]="true"
attribute2="true"
```

Here, attribute1 will be passed the boolean value true and attribute2 will be passed the string value "true".

Comment: I missed the switch from formControl to formControlName.  I will update my question so it shows that more clearly then accept your answer

Comment: Yes, I think this switch is easy to miss. It would be better if they wouldn't use `name` as the property of the component's FormControl.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit [] then input value is treated like a string: `input="name"`, in this case `this.input === 'name'`.

To achieve the same result using [] you will have to do `[input]="'name'"` or if you have public field `public name:string = 'name'` then you can also `[input]="name"`.

So it should be `[formControlName]="'name'"`.

Comment: This definitely allows the use of the [],   but I still did not understand what was going on, the fact that I missed the switch  from formControl to formControlName is what through me off.